# How to do t-test after matching in MatchThem

Tags: matching, r-mice, causality, propensity-score-matching

Through `matchthem()`, I have got `matched.datasets`. Then I want to check the balance of
covariates between two matched groups through t-test or p-value. But the `cobalt` package could not show p-value or t-test results.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done and should not be done. It is inappropriate to compute p-values to assess or report balance. Reasons for this are explained in the `cobalt` [vignette](https://ngreifer.github.io/cobalt/articles/cobalt.html#whats-missing-in-cobalt) and references therein. `cobalt` provides ample statistics to use to assess balance that are appropriate.